# Which is better: storing string including Unicode characters in NVARCHAR or VARCHAR?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, informix

I want to store the string including Unicode character.

I know there are two choices. NVARCHAR and VARCHAR. NVARCHAR uses 2 bytes to store a character; however VARCHAR uses 1 byte for a character.

In terms of storing 2 2-byte unicode character each of them  uses 4 bytes. But when it comes to storing 1 1-byte ansi character and 1 2-byte unicode character, NVARCHAR uses 4 bytes, and VARCHAR uses 3 bytes.

So I think using VARCHAR is more compact and always be the better method. I don't know if my understand above is right or not because there should be some advances that NVARCHAR is over VARCHAR.

Comment: AFAIK , NVARCHAR only will help you when you use a different collate and need to sort this information according .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smaller => faster.
But beware of indexes and the type of data you present it *1.
And beware of the different datatypes in different types of database servers *2

*1) In MSSQL:
When you have an index over a VARCHAR column and present it a Unicode String, MSSQL-Server does not make use of the index. The same thing happens when you present a BigInt to a indexed-column containing SmallInt. Even if the BigInt is small enough to be a SmallInt, SQL-Server is not able to use the index.
The other way around you do not have this problem (when providing SmallInt or Ansi-Code to an indexed BigInt ot NVARCHAR column).

*2) Know that every database has slightly different datatypes and VARCHAR does not means the same everywhere. While MSSQL has VARCHAR and NVARCHAR, an Apache/Derby database has only VARCHAR and there VARCHAR is in Unicode.